# Recursive function charts

Tags: javascript, charts

```
function add() {
            myChart.data.labels.push(Math.random());
            myChart.data.datasets[0].data.push(Math.random());
            myChart.update();
            setTimeout(add(), 1000);
        }
```

I tried to make a recursive function with setTimeout.
that function generates random value on the chart but without "setTimeout" it works but if i insert "setTimeout" the chart doesn't appear.. browser page completely empty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`setTimeout` takes a reference to a function -- `add`

not the result of a function -- `add()`

try it like this...

```
setTimeout(add, 1000);
```